# How can I Fix a broken plastic screw hole

Tags: screws

One side of a plastic screw hole completely broke so the screw cannot screw on, is a way I can repair it?
I cannot add another hole because it’s on a electronic keyboard

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with home improvement.

Comment: A slightly larger screw will often do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the screw hole, mix some quick setting epoxy and form it into a side. You'll have to keep forming it until it hardens. Maybe wrap some tape around the side that's not broken and make a "form" to put the epoxy in. Once it's cured, drill a hole for the screw

Comment: I would drill *and tap* the hole.  Epoxy can be tough and brittle.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Good point. Even the self threading screws for plastic would probably crack the epoxy.